# QToolBox default aspect differs between mac linux and windows

Tags: qt, toolbox, aspect

When I create a new QToolBox in Qt designer under Mac or Linux i
see the following aspect (tabbed):
     [tabbed aspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQPws.png)
but in the same Qt project under Windows The QToolBox appears like this (boxed):
     [boxed aspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TyDn.png)

How can I change the aspect of (boxed) to (tabbed) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found how to:

In C++ code, reference the widget with findChild
then, then use setStyle with QStyleFactory to set the right aspect:

#include <QStyleFactory>
...
QToolBox *mytoolbox = findChild("toolBox");
mytoolbox->setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"));

this worked for me.